# Synchronising images in the filesystem with the live server

Tags: php, upload, synchronization

I have a local PHP web application that is being updated daily with new content and updated content. This is store in MYSQL5.

I am also maintaining a filesystem of related images, that are tracked by a table in the mysql.  I have NOT gone down the blob route - this is using a linux filesystem.

Having performed a daily update on the data what is the best method to synchronise the images with the server?

I am using PHP5, but not adverse to external scheduling program it works.

My images are stored in such order:

```
media/id/imagename.jpg
```

ie.

```
media/123/123_1.jpg
media/123/123_2.jpg
media/1234/1234_1.jpg
media/1234/1234_2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Nomrally the answer to the question of how to keep files in sync would be to use a tool designed for the job - like rsync, or use a replicated / shared filesystem. However in your case, presumably you want to the mysql records to reflect the state of the files.

In order to do this I would recommend writing a pair of PHP scripts (one at the sending end, one at the receiving end). To add some security in here, I'd not let the receiving end capture any old data - but rather have the origin server make a request to the receiving end providing the metadata - the receiving end would then poll the image data from the origin to create the copy (and write the mysql record when this has completed).

It might be a good idea to think about implementing some sort of transactional control too - to sensure that both ends are in sync without having to copy every file.

Comment: If I am honest that is what I implement in an earlier version, but I was polling so much information it was taking a very long time on a record by record basis.

So I thought it would be best to do it all in one go, then upload it in one go. Its not occured to me (late in the day) that if i do a mysql master-slave sync, the images will not be present until the large upload.

HELP!

Comment: OK - so why not use mysql replication to copy the metadata then implement the file replication in the 404 handler?

Comment: Could you elaborate please - specifically regarding the 404 handler. Im not sure where you are going with this. Thanks

Comment: On the 'slave', set the 404 handler to point to a php script. When the script fires for a URL of a replicated image, have the script try to fetch the image file from the origin and serve it up, leaving a copy in the appropriate local dir.